# Unable to login to vtiger MYC Portal

Tags: vtiger

I am using vtiger 6.4 and configured the myc portal with it. I can see the portal url in crm> settings> customer portal. I have set the outgoing server settings and when I add any contact in the crm so the email is being sent on the contact's email id containing the customer portal credentials but when I try to login to the portal using these credentials I am unable to login as well the system is not showing any error for this. Kindly advice where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the display_errors = On with display_errors = Off in your php.ini file.it works for me.